# Why does this text overlap the icon with the my current setup on the mobile version?

Tags: wordpress, footer

I am working on this footer and it tends not to work the way I want it to. Basically, the issue now is that once I go from desktop to smaller mobile resolutions I made so that two images get away, one currently stays. So it is like this>

Desktop
ROW 1 - Left image, center image - right image
Row 2 - Centralized text.

But when I go to mobile I want (!!) it to becomes like this
ROW 1 / Center imgae
Row 2 / Centralized text

However, when it gets smaller it all gets meshed up so the text overlaps the center image. I could potentially hide it but it would be great if it could get put under. Here is the code I am using.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: #5C6568;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: center;

  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background:#5C6568;
}
.flex-container2 > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Cardo;
  background:#5C6568;
}

footer #footer-riba {
    left: 7cm;
}
footer #footer-intbau {
    right: 7cm;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
   #footer-riba, #footer-intbau, #pinkriba, #footer-mega-col-wrap, #flex-container2 {
    display: none;
  }}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div><img id="footer-riba" src="https://test3.rental-academy.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/INTBAU-v3-same-size-as-RIBA-01-300x79.png"></div>
  <div> <center><img id="greylogo" src="https://test3.rental-academy.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/John-Simpson-Architects-Logo-Transparenthalf-01.png"></center></div>
  <div><img id="footer-intbau" src="https://test3.rental-academy.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/ribaWhite2-300x79.png"></div>  
</div>
<div class="flex-container2">

  <div>JOHN SIMPSON ARCHITECTS LTD. | 29 Great James St, London WC1N 3ES, UK | +44 20 7 405 1285 | info@johnsimpsonarchitects.com | <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/john-simpson-architects-london-limited" style="color: white">linkedin</a></div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>

<footer>
      
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed why now! So before I centralized it using center-command (the center png) but after removing those around it and using the flex, those made it not needed. Removing those made it work fine!